# Middle click in OS X

Tags: mac, mouse

I recently got a Mac, however I am using a Microsoft mouse.

For some reason clicking the middle (scroll wheel) button shows the <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> dialog (all windows in a side by side list).

How can I make the middle button work as a middle button - so I can use it to open links in a new tab in Firefox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In System Preferences, go to the "Microsoft Mouse" settings. Click on the "Wheel button" button and choose "Handled by Mac OS".

If you haven't already installed the Microsoft drivers, you won't have this preferences pane. Go to microsoft.com and download the appropriate software for your mouse.

Comment: The online form doesn't seem to work for me at http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/download/download.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If it has an OS X driver, look in the settings for that. There are shareware mouse drivers such as SteerMouse, but there should be some that comes with your mouse.